# A better "better"

Tags: synonyms

What is an adjective that can be used in the place of *better* that is synonomous, less over-used, and more interesting?

Comment: How should this better better be better than better? Without knowing how to better better, we'll never be able to better better with a better that's betterer!

Comment: Can you give a fuller example?  Better is very good at comparatives, which is its function. In some circumstances, there may be a more appropriate word - but in this case, there is nothing to go on...

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think we'll get clarification on the question, since the poster's account is inactive.

Comment: Have you considered consulting a [thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/better)?

Comment: What about "best"?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=synonyms+better

Answer (score 6):

Well, the best way to improve on the generic word 'better' is to state the specific way in which thing A exceeds thing B, for example:

A cat is a *more manageable* pet than a dog. (Cats are better because they're more manageable)

The latest model is *more efficient* than the last. (The latest model's increased efficiency makes it better than the last one)

Where 'better' is used to mean, 'of increased quality relative to', *superior* is an option, as in:

Cats are *superior to* dogs.
This model is *superior to* the last.

'*Greater*' is another option, but that has a quantitative sense to it, so you use it where 'more' of whatever quality is being considered is 'better', so '*greater* resolving power', 'greater miles per gallon', etc.

Finally, where 'better' means more acceptable or advantageous, '*preferable*' or '*preferably*' are options. So:

It would be better to take the stairs/It would be (more) *preferable* to take the stairs
Cakes are better made from scratch/Cakes are *preferably* made from scratch

Credit goes to merriam-webster.com for preferable/preferably.

Comment: There's a lot of great synonyms in this answer, could you improve the answer by **emphasising** those words?